# Do the bundle activate and deactivate methods needs to be synchronized in osgi

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

We have a component and defined activate and deactivate methods on it. We are creating some objects in activate method and in deactivate we are cleaning it up. Do we need to synchronize the the objects that are being created as multiple calls to activate deactivate can happen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a strict "happens before" relationship between the call made to the activate and deactivate methods. This means that it is both guaranteed that your [activate method will finish *before* the deactivate method is called](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#service.component-activation), *and* that the relevant memory barriers will be passed to make sure that any fields you set in activation are visible in deactivation.

The important thing to deal with from a synchronisation perspective is to ensure that any *dynamic* references that your component has are handled in a thread-safe way. These references can be rebound while your component is still running, and therefore need to cope with concurrent changes.

Answer (score 1):

Declarative services component objects are only used for one activate, deactivate cycle. There will be only one call to these methods.

If a component is activated again a new java object is created for it.